# How to create a Tabbed Activity with ListViews - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

First of all, I'm a beginner in Android programming. What I'm trying to do is to program three Tabs with each a ListView inside (you know it from e.g. WhatsApp). Android Studio makes it easy to automatically create a Tabbed Activity. So the question is: how can I implement a ListView for each Tab? 
Actually there is a nice tutorial on http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/ which uses TabActivity. However this method is deprecated and Fragments should be used instead. I have extended main_fragment.xml (which was created by Android Studio) with a ListView. But what is the correct way to set the corresponding list adapters and especially where to set them? Setting them like `ListView list_all = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAll)` in `onCreate()` does not work because of a null object reference error. Also I didn't find out how to use the `rootView` which is returned by `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)` So how can I solve this problem?

main_fragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"

    tools:context="de.url.members">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:background="@color/bg_login_dark"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/bg_login_dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main.java:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    // The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            // action here
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_members, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.logout) {
            //action here
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            int sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);//INDEX of selected TAB
            View rootView;

            if (sectionNumber == 1){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
            }else if (sectionNumber == 2){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);                 
            }else if (sectionNumber == 3){
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);                  
            }else{
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section1);
                case 1:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section2);
                case 2:
                    return getResources().getString(R.string.title_section3);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Listing with tablayout and viewpager try this way it will work for you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Toolbar toolbar;
    private static ViewPager viewPager;
    private static TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);//setting tab over viewpager

        //Implementing tab selected listener over tablayout
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());//setting current selected item over viewpager
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        Log.e("TAG","TAB1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.e("TAG","TAB2");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Log.e("TAG","TAB3");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }


    //Setting View Pager
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment("ANDROID"), "ANDROID");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment("iOS"), "iOS");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment("WINDOWS"), "WINDOWS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    //View Pager fragments setting adapter class
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();//fragment arraylist
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();//title arraylist

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }


        //adding fragments and title method
        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

For more see [android-material-design-tabs-using-tablayout](http://www.androhub.com/android-material-design-tabs-using-tablayout/)

OR

Check this http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/10/Android-Sliding-TabLayout-ListView-WhatsApp.html

And check this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: wah bhura wah ! !

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what you have to do to put a ListView on one of the fragments. (Sorry if I write a bad English)

You should put your listView view on the xml witch is displayed by one of your fragments. In the code that you have post the layout witch fragment displays is R.layout.main_fragment

Then on the fragment you have to declare your ListView:

`ListView list_all = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewAll);`

You have to create a ListView adapter, an object class and some other files, you can use the tutorial witch you have post.

[Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/)

Then write your code to set an Adapter to this ListView after the rootView is assigned on the fragment:

```
if (sectionNumber == 1){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        }else if (sectionNumber == 2){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);                 
        }else if (sectionNumber == 3){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);                  
        }else{
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
}

ArrayList<Object> arrayListOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
arrayListOfObjects.add(new Object(...));
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arrayListOfObjects);
list_all.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now by simply editing the `getItem()` method of `public class SectionsPagerAdapter` in main.java.
Just return a default ListFragment instead of the PlaceholderFragment. 
Interesting note: Returning the same ListFragment object for all tabs leads to an error.

main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private ListFragment contacts1 = new ListFragment();
    private ListFragment contacts2 = new ListFragment();
    private ListFragment contacts3 = new ListFragment();

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        words.add("Hello");
        words.add("World");
        words.add("!");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item,words);
        contacts1.setListAdapter(adapter);
        contacts2.setListAdapter(adapter);
        contacts3.setListAdapter(adapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Update List", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                words.add("New Item");
                adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public ListFragment getItem(int position) {

            if (position == 0){
                return contacts1;
            }else if (position == 1){
                return contacts2;
            }else{
                return contacts3;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```